# "Automatically Start MySQL Server on Startup" not working on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-mountain-lion

Recently I've upgraded from OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard to OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. I've noticed that MySQL doesn't automatically start anymore despite of the option turned on in my system preferences.

I have no problems with activating/deactivating it manually, MySQL works fine.

Does anyone have a solution for this? It's not a big problem but if it can be fixed it saves me 5 more seconds each day! :)

Thanks in advance!
Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They've changed stuffs in mountain lion,
here is a guide for how making AMP work in your new envioroment
http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion

If you only need the MySQL part, jump to that part :).

Comment: I've reinstalled the StartUp component and everything is back to normal. Didn't think it would be that easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Symlink your mysql plist into your Mac LaunchAgents. If mysql plist is located in /usr/local/opt/mysql/ then the following should work:

```
 #> ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```